# DataView.Filter not working with multiple % in "like %"?

Tags: sql, dataview, rowfilter

Below SQL query works when the spaces in the role name are replaced by %:  1 row is returned

select * from cmrdata.dbo.tblRoles where rolename like '%Super%Administrator%'

However, when I try to mimic the same in DataView.RowFilter, it does not return any rows.

```
dv.RowFilter = "RoleName like '[%]" & Replace(roleName, " ", "[%]") & "[%]'"
```

I also tried without the [] around the %. Please advise.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly suggest using

```
WHERE role_name like "%SUPER%" 
  AND role_name like "%ADMINISTRATOR%"
```

or

```
WHERE role_name like "%SUPER ADMINISTRATOR%"
```

Don't forget; regular expressions are always there for you if criterion gets to complex.

Cheers.

Comment: for this, I have to break the role name into multiple words. 

How can I use regular expressions instead?

Comment: Use this article; 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql

Answer (score 0):

Error in Like operator: the string pattern '%super%administrator%' is invalid.

Why are you replacing spaces with a %?  What type of rows are you trying to match?

Comment: Purpose: I am checking to see if a role with that name already exists. If a role with the same name does not exist, then I insert the new role into the system.

I want to ignore spaces when checking if the role name exists