# SQL Server regular expressions kleene star

Tags: sql-server, regex

is there a regular expression operator that can do what clean star did?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star

I know I could write 'jdslf[a-f]%' however I wish for an expression such as 
'jdslf[[a-f]*]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure T-SQL not.
Compare [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql)

I can't say anything about CLR solutions yet. It might be possible.