# How to use regular expression in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

For example:

```
where strword match with {%{J{GC * GC}J} or strword={%{J{GC * GC}J}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql

Comment: @Roman - It is a very similar question but other post specifically states they do not want a CLR approach.  If this poster is OK with CLR then it might not be a duplicate question.

Comment: "Native" T-SQL has no regular expression support - you'll need e.g. a SQL-CLR library (.NET library) to add this capability

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I typically try to avoid posting answers that are simply links to somewhere else.  But in this case it's a fairly big answer as you have to involve CLR in your approach.

So - in this case I'm going to make an exception and just give you a link.  I feel better about it since it's an official Microsoft doc and they are pretty good about not moving things around.

[Here's the walk through from Microsoft on using RegEx with SQLServer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)

It has good sample code and is extensive in it's coverage.  If your OK with adding CLR to your solution then it should give you exactly what you need.

**Update:** Turns out Microsoft did in fact change that link.  Another walk through by a respected company (Red Gate) can be found here:  https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/