# Repeating characters in T-SQL LIKE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

Problem:
Limit the value of a `VARCHAR` variable (or a column) to digits and ASCI characters, but allow variable length.
This script will not yield required result:

```
declare @var as VARCHAR (150)
select @var = '123ABC'

if (@var LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,150}')
    print 'OK'
else
    print 'Not OK'
```

Anyone have idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the not carat ^, and a NOT LIKE expression.

So you say, where not like not non-alphanumeric ;) This works for standard numbers & characters:

```
declare @var as VARCHAR (150)
select @var = '123ABC'

if (@var NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%')
    print 'OK'
else
    print 'Not OK'
```

Edit: Thanks Martin for the collation hint, if you want the characters like ý treated as non-alphanumeric add in the COLLATE as below

```
declare @var as VARCHAR (150)
select @var = '123ABCý'

if (@var NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN ) 
    print 'OK'
else
    print 'Not OK'
```

Comment: You might need a binary collate clause in there as well. Without it it can return additional characters `SELECT number, CHAR(number) FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='P' AND number between 0 and 255 and CHAR(number) NOT LIKE '%[^a-z^A-Z^0-9]%'`

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks, hadn't considered the odd characters, they didn't crop up for me when I had to do this years ago, but they could for the asker. Many thanks.

Comment: Also the pattern needs to be `NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'`. Without that the caret matches. With it the earlier query brings back 62 rows as expected.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks again, fixed. My word you have a lot of points :)

Comment: Just another thing...
Any idea how to extend the list of allowed characters with special ones ([]%^*)? How to combine caret (^) and ESCAPE characters?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Forget the question.
This works fine:
if (@var NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9!@!.!_!:!-!%![]%' ESCAPE '!')

Answer (score 1):

Will this help

```
Declare @t table (Alphanumeric VARCHAR(100))
Insert Into @t 
Select '123ABCD' Union All Select 'ABC' Union All 
Select '123'  Union All  Select  '123ABCý' Union All
Select 'a-z123' Union All  Select 'abc123' Union All
Select 'a1b2c3d4'


SELECT Alphanumeric
FROM @t 
WHERE Alphanumeric LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%' 
AND ( Alphanumeric NOT LIKE  '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) 
AND LEN(Alphanumeric)> 6 -- display records having more than a length of 6
```

//Result

**Alphanumeric**

```
123ABCD
a1b2c3d4
```

N.B.~ Used Martin's collation hint..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL doesn't support RegEx.

You can use [SQL CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498.aspx) to run such expression though.

---

Also try the [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) function:

```
if (LEN(@var) <= 150)
    print 'OK'
else
    print 'Not OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL doesn’t support regex, closest you can get is the [`PATINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) function that you can use to match specific characters, but you can’t specify the count.
You can try combining it with the `LEN` function to check the length.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql) page for a few examples of `PATINDEX`.