# Setting length of LIKE in SELECT with regex?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an Access SQL query that includes a select on a text like

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE "abc#####";
```

where the value to be found has a string length of 8 characters, begins with "abc" and ends with 5 numbers.

I am attempting to translate this into a SQL Server (2005) query on a varchar column and first came up with this:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'abc_____';
```

But of course this matches values with non-numerics in the last 5 characters.  So instead I've been using the following:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'abc[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

This works, but is there a more efficient/accepted way to handle this type of select? (Is there another special character that works like the underscore `_` but for numerics?)

Comment: SQL is just verbose.  Get to know all the tricks of your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @pattern varchar(max) = 'abc#####'

SET @pattern = REPLACE(@pattern,'#','[0-9]')
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE @pattern
```

Comment: Thanks, that also works (with minor adjustment for SQL Server 2005 - `DECLARE` can't also set values until 2008+). I was hoping to reduce the amount of code as I'm programmatically generating these statements, but I guess you gotta use what's available.

Comment: Do need to programmatically generate the statements?  `SELECT column FROM table INNER JOIN pattern_list ON column LIKE pattern` http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT column FROM table
WHERE substring(column, 1, 3) = 'abc'
AND substring(column, 4, LEN(column)-3) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

**References**:

[Repeating characters in T-SQL LIKE condition on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246156/repeating-characters-in-t-sql-like-condition)