# Analogue for regex '?' (preceding item optional) in T-SQL like?

Tags: regex, t-sql

I am wondering, is it possible to translate regex containing '?' (preceding item optional) in T-SQL LIKE pattern? Without any actions on the DB side. For example, `"^31-?4"`. I could split it up into several clauses, but if regex contains a lot of '?' this is not that convenient.

Comment: Since this question is really old check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql
Oracle databases now support regex

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`LIKE` doesn't use regular expressions and the pattern language it uses doesn't have tokens and qualifiers, [just a few placeholders](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms179859.aspx):

```
Wildcard character    Description
------------------    -----------
%                     Any string of zero or more characters.
_ (underscore)        Any single character.
[ ]                   Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef]).
[^ ]                  Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef]).
```

So no, there isn't such a thing you ask for.