# SQL Server Pattern -Finding records from F1AGE-F20AGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, pattern-matching, sql-like

I tried checking pattern using

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST 
WHERE QUESTION LIKE '%F[1-9]AGE%`
```

trying to find `F1AGE` - `F9AGE` (which is correct).

| Column A |
| --- |
| F1AGE |
| F2AGE |
| F3AGE |
| F4AGE |
| F5AGE |
| F6AGE |
| F7AGE |
| F8AGE |
| F9AGE |
| F10AGE |
| F11AGE |
| F12AGE |
| F13AGE |
| F14AGE |
| F15AGE |
| F16AGE |
| F17AGE |
| F18AGE |
| F19AGE |
| F20AGE |

Is there any solution for `'F1AGE'`-`'F20AGE'`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as [you can't make characters optional with `LIKE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053688/analogue-for-regex-preceding-item-optional-in-t-sql-like), I suspect you really need to use an `OR` with a second condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST 
WHERE QUESTION LIKE '%F[1-9]AGE%'
   OR QUESTION LIKE '%F[1-2][0-9]AGE%'
```

If we really want to be precise on pattern matching, assuming you don't want values higher than 20, you would need three conditions instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST 
WHERE QUESTION LIKE '%F[1-9]AGE%'
   OR QUESTION LIKE '%F1[0-9]AGE%'
   OR QUESTION LIKE '%F20AGE%'
```