# sql server extract the "like substring"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I would like to get the "like substring" of select statement.

MyTable:

```
Container      ItemName

101            QQQ A12 DDD
101            QQTT A12 R33 
102            QQQ A3 AB3
103            QQ BB BB11
```

The select statement work fine to get the rows (records) I need (without the "like substring")

```
SELECT Container, <like substring>
  FROM MyTable
  Where (ItemName like '%A[0-9] %') OR (ItemName like '%A[0-9][0-9] %')
  GROUP BY Container, <like substring>
```

As a result I hope to get:

```
Container      "like substring"

101            A12
102            A3
```

The real question is how to get(display) the substring found by the like logical operator

How should I do it?

Thanks
Yossi

Comment: Yossi, it is realy unclear what you are asking.

Comment: As SQL Server does not support regular expressions (apart from it's non-standard LIKE "extension") I don't think you can do it with T-SQL

Answer (score 3):

This is not something that you can do with sql. Though the [`LIKE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) and [`PATINDEX`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/198986/51) do expose some features similar to regular-expressions, they are just used to filter the rows that meet the given criteria.

You are looking to do the equivalent of extracting a regex grouping within the `Select` section of the query, something that you can't do with native transact-sql. This is something that would be more appropriate to perform in your application code, after the results of the query have been returned.