# SQL script for removing extra characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I've got MSSQL 2012 database with some data issues in the certain column A which contains text.

There are many occurences of aditional unnecesarry character after the `</B>` tag, for instance:

```
'<B>Something</B>g' where should stand '<B>Something</B>'
'<B>SomethingElse</B>e' where should stand '<B>SomethingElse</B>'
```

Previous values are part of a greater text, for instance and can occur more than once -> Column example:

```
'Some text is here <B>Something</B>g and also here <B>SomethingElse</B>e more text'
```

Those 'extra' characters are always the same as the last character between the `<B></B>` tags.
I would like to create SQL scripts which will:

1. Remove extra character after `</B>` tag
2. Only if extra character is the same as the last character between the
   `<B></B>` tags (as a aditional check). EDIT: This is not absolutely necessary

I assuming there is a way of calling replace function, like in this pseudo in which X represents any character.

```
replace(X</B>X, X</B>);
```

But I am not very good in SQL and also I don't know how to implement 2. check.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible dublicate , try:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql]

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2012. Thanks............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column has no other characters then just those strings, you could use this `update` statement on column `a`:

```
update  mytable
set     a = left(a, len(a)-1)
where   left(right(a, 6), 5) = right(a, 1) + '</B>'
```

Here are some test cases in a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c9e0/1).

To replace such occurrences in longer strings, where there might be multiple of them, then you can use this [recursive query](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
WITH recursive AS (
    SELECT replace(a, '</B>', 'µ') as a
    FROM   mytable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT stuff(a, charindex('µ', a),
           CASE WHEN substring(a, charindex('µ', a)-1, 1)
                   = substring(a, charindex('µ', a)+1, 1)
                THEN 2 
                ELSE 1 
           END, '</B>')
    FROM   recursive
    WHERE  charindex('µ', a) > 0
)
SELECT * 
FROM   recursive
WHERE  charindex('µ', a) = 0
```

The character `µ` that appears in several places should be a character that you do not expect to ever have in your data. Replace it by another character if necessary.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be427/1).

The above query turned into an update statement looks like below. It assumes that your table has a primary key *id*:

```
WITH recursive AS (
    SELECT id, 
           replace(a, '</B>', 'µ') as a,
           0 as modified
    FROM   mytable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 
           stuff(a, charindex('µ', a),
           CASE WHEN substring(a, charindex('µ', a)-1, 1)
                   = substring(a, charindex('µ', a)+1, 1)
              THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, '</B>'),
           1
    FROM   recursive
    WHERE  charindex('µ', a) > 0
)
UPDATE     mytable
SET        a = recursive.a
FROM       recursive
INNER JOIN mytable 
        ON mytable.id = recursive.id 
WHERE      charindex('µ', recursive.a) = 0 
AND        recursive.modified = 1;
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9d4d/1) for that as well.

Comment: I just edited. The answer is fine but in my case the column consist not only  "<B>value</B>v" but it could consist arbitrary text everywhere, e.g "This is some text <B>value</B>e  and once more <B>values</B>s and here"

Comment: Ok, thanks. If it is very difficult, the check under 2) is not absolutely necessary

Comment: Added solution for that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveChars] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @InputStr NVARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SearchStr NVARCHAR(4) = '</B>'
    DECLARE @LastChar CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @LastCharInStr CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(50)

    SET @LastChar = SUBSTRING(@InputStr, 
                    CHARINDEX(@SearchStr, @InputStr) + LEN(@SearchStr), 1)
    SET @LastCharInStr = SUBSTRING(@InputStr, 
                         CHARINDEX(@SearchStr, @InputStr) - 1, 1)

    IF (@LastCharInStr = @LastChar) 
            SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@InputStr, 0, 
            CHARINDEX(@SearchStr, @InputStr) + LEN(@SearchStr))
    ELSE
        SET @Result = @InputStr

    RETURN @Result
END
```

And then call it:

```
UPDATE MyTable
Set A = dbo.RemoveChars(A)
```

Personally I would create a second function to only apply the updates to the values that have a difference between the last char in the string and the char after the  but that's for you to decide.

Comment: I just spotted @trincot 's answer and I guess it is far simpler than what I provided you with and his answer includes the conditional part already saving you having to create second function.