# Regex Pattern in sql

Tags: sql, regex

I have a tested regex pattern and I need to use it in SQL(SMS software), I am not finding any syntax to write the general form

```
   ((\d{1,2})-([A-Z]{1,2}))
```

I have to use it as all the combinations in Patindex as

```
   PATINDEX('%[0-9]-[A-Z]%', lower([NAME]))>0 or
   PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]"-[A-Z][A-Z]%', lower([NAME]))>0 or .......
```

Is there any method through which directly REGEX can be used as

```
   PATINDEX('%[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z]{1,2}%', lower([NAME]))>0
```

Comment: You cannot use regex with PATINDEX. You need some UDF, I believe.See [*SQL Server Regular expressions in T-SQL*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql).

Comment: @wiktor: Thanks for the link, but 

 https://stackoverflow.com/a/30877281/7289324

is the only link that looks promising, but I doubt if it will accept the pattern-

 PATINDEX('%[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z]{1,2}%', lower([NAME]))>0

Have u tested it any time?

Comment: PATINDEX does not accept a regex. `{n,m}` is a limiting quantifier that can only be used in regex. PATINDEX patterns do not allow quantifiers.

Comment: @Wikitor: thanks for reply, so is there any method to write regex in the format    ('%[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z]{1,2}%', lower([NAME])),  any other function in sql?