# Regular expresions MS SQL. How use in select.

Tags: sql-server

I need to write select that gives me records which in field SerialNumber have only string like this   MT and some numbers. For example MT34234234 or MT455. 
I dont want other records for example with value MTA424 or MT23423423BBA. 
I write this reqular expresion:

```
select * from 
MyTable
where  SerialNumber like 'MT%[0-9]'
```

But it gives me record with value MTA424. Can somebody help me how i can fix my query?

Comment: SQL server doesnt support regex, if 2016 or above you can use R services along with SQL Server. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server)

Comment: `%` is zero or more characters, so `like 'MT[0-9]'` should do what you want.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of checking for MT at the beginning of the string and then non-numeric characters after the first 2 places of the string.

```
declare @table table (SerialNumber varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('MT34234234'),
('MT455'),
('MTA424'),
('MT23423423BBA')

select * from @table
where SerialNumber like 'MT%'
and right(SerialNumber,len(SerialNumber) - 2) not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: Almost there! Just try this:

Comment: Can you elaborate @StelioK? I think your comment cut off

Comment: My bad, that was intended for my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Ryan said, there are no real regular expressions in SQL-Server. However, you can get to your desired selection by adding a second condition like

```
select * from MyTable
where  SerialNumber like 'MT%'
and SerialNumber not like 'MT%[^0-9]%'
```

(I modified the first condition too.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE SerialNumber LIKE 'MT%'
    AND SerialNumber NOT LIKE 'MT%[a-zA-Z]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgresql you can do something like this:

```
select * from 
MyTable
where  regexp_like(SerialNumber, '^MT\d*') // or '^MT\d+' as you want
```

Answer (score -4):

Almost there! Just try this:

```
select  *
from    mytable
where   serialnumber like 'MT[0-9]%[^a-z]'
```

Comment: this would match MT1ZYZ